# Spring AOP aspect inconsistent behaviour with pointcuts for Spring Data Repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop, spring-data-rest

**Context**

I am using AOP to create/remove Spring ACL records for managed entities by intercepting Spring Data repositories' save and delete methods. All my repositories are `@RepositoryRestResource` annotated interfaces extending either `PagingAndSortingRepository` or `CrudRepository`. This has been working perfectly in the past. Unfortunately I can't identify exactly the point in time (or code change) where it stopped working.

**Expected behaviour**

The following advice should fire on all save methods.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.*.save(*))")
public void defaultRepoSave() {}

// may be useful for overridden methods
@Pointcut("execution(* com.xxx.yyy.repository.*.save(..))")
public static void customRepoSave() {}

@Pointcut("defaultRepoSave() || customRepoSave()")
public static void repoSave() {}

@Around(value="repoSave() && args(entity)", argNames="entity")
public Object aroundSave(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Object entity) throws Throwable{
    log.info("Saving ...");
    return pjp.proceed();
}
```

*Note: I tried various combinations of `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy=true/false, proxyTargetClass=true/false)`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on this particular advice*

**The issue**

The advice fires for some repositories, and not for others. Both repositories are in the same package. Debugging shows that both repositories are proxied, but the execution for the one on the left is missing advice-related interceptors altogether. The one on the right proceeds as expected.

[image: Screenshot]

To eliminate the possibility of pointcut mismatch I created a custom annotation and added to the .save() method in both repositories.

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface AclManaged {}
```

Used as:

```
@Override
@AclManaged
Entity1 save(Entity1 entity);
```

And the advice:

```
@Around("@annotation(aclManaged)")
public Object aclManaged(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, AclManaged aclManaged) throws Throwable {
    log.info("Acl managed");
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Same story - the annotation works in one repository but doesn't fire for the repository where the `execution(..save..)` pointcut had failed.

For testing purposes I am invoking both methods by POSTing an empty entity from Postman to each respective repository rest endpoint. However the same issue happens when the repository is invoked directly from my code.

The repositories code for the sake of completeness (the inconsistent behaviour occurs even with the most basic repo implementation):

--- EDIT: I simplified the repositories to the bare minimum ---

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "entity1s", path = "entity1s")
public interface Entity1Repository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity1, Long> {

    // this is the method that is supposed to fire two distinct advices
    @Override
    @AclManaged
    Entity1 save(Entity1 entity);
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "entity2s", path = "entity2s")
public interface Entity2Repository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Entity2, Long> {


    // both aspects match perfectly
    @Override
    @AclManaged
    Entity2 save(Entity2 ics);


}
```

**Questions**

What can be blocking the AOP aspects? How does Spring populate the invocation interceptor chain?

What's the best way to troubleshoot AOP aspects? (given both execution and annotation pointcuts fail)

On a slightly different note - is it advisable to use JPA auditing for ACL management instead of AOP?

**Versions**

spring 5.0.8.RELEASE, spring data rest 3.0.9.RELEASE, spring data jpa 2.0.9.RELEASE (all managed by Spring Boot 2.0.4)

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be caused by an unfortunate combination of Spring Booot's `@Enable...` annotations and my `@Configuration` classes. The framework seems to have a few different ways to determine class/interface proxying (stemming from `@EnableCaching`, `@EnableTransactionManagement`, `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, `@EnableAsync`). In certain situations they seem to hijack the expected behaviour. I was able to restore the expected behaviour by:

- Adding `proxyTargetClass=true` to all `@Enable..` annotations
- Moving the `@Enable...` annotations to relevant `@Configuration` classes

I wasn't able to determine which combination in particular was causing the inconsistent behaviour i.e. I don't have a minimal replicable test case.

I am still interested in a more erudite insight as to the root causes behind the inconsistent MethodInvocationInterceptor chains.